# recently viewed product collection is empty in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, collection, recently-viewed

I have added a code in **Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

       <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" name="recently_viewed" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml" group="detailed_info">     
            <arguments>
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Recently Viewed</argument>
              <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
            </arguments>                
            <action method="setPageSize">
                    <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
                </action>                   
        </block>    
    </referenceBlock>
```

The above code showing only the recently viewed tab, but products are not showing.

Here i am attaching the screenshot,

[image]

Please anyone look into it and update me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" name="recently_viewed" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" after="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="uiComponent" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed</argument>
        <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">4</argument>
        <argument name="show_attributes" xsi:type="string">name,image,price,learn_more</argument>
        <argument name="show_buttons" xsi:type="string">add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: I am trying include this in tabs, can i use this code?

Comment: yes you can try

Comment: yes, this working for me, thanks, can we resize the product image there, like upsell prdoucts image size.

Comment: please attach screen-shot

Comment: thanks, i made it working..

Comment: ohk bro nop happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94578/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: but one small issue, price is not showing, its showing only product name and image there

Comment: can you please update me, I am getting this error in console, knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return isMsrpApplicable($row()) }"
Message: isMsrpApplicable is not defined

Comment: can you check it please?

Comment: ohk i will check and update soon

Comment: @Rathod, can you help on this issue,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277561/images-are-not-loading-after-upgrade-to-magento-2-3-0

Comment: yes let me check

Comment: @Rathod, could u get the time to check it?